# Select and then Insert Query (PHP with MYSQLI) Not working

Tags: php, mysqli, insert, count

Hello I've a table named as "register" in which i've some records Lets says (10)
I want to first count that records and then save it into another table named as "not" i.e. Notification(Handler Name)

Here's the code which i'm using but unfortunately its not working..

Here's my config.php

```
<?php

$con = new mysqli('localhost','root','','admin');

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

and here's abc.php

```
<?php 
include('config.php');
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO not VALUES((SELECT count(*) as count FROM register))";
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
if($result2->num_rows>0)
{
while($rw1=$result2->fetch_array())
{
$value1 =  $rw1['count'];
echo $value1;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: `NOT` is a reserved word in SQL. I recommend using a different table name. Posting your schema would help us understand your problem better. This is the [correct INSERT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html). Also - I cannot see any `mysqli_connect()` in your code.

Comment: change your table name as suggested by @phpPhil plus try this query
INSERT INTO not SELECT count(*) as count FROM register

Comment: @phpPhil perhaps he made connection in config.php file .

Answer (score 0):

change your table name as suggested by @phpPhil

plus try this query

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO not SELECT count(*) as count FROM register";
```

**UPDATED**
made your connection in this file.

```
$con = new mysqli('localhost','root','','admin');
$sql = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM register";
```

this query will return only one or zero rows so dont use while

```
 $result = $con->quer($sql) or die($con->error); 
    if($result->num_rows>0)
    {
         $rw=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
         $value =  $rw['count'];
```

**echo $value;** here to check what you get here

//preiously you had check if value is not empty. which is wrong because it will never empty it will either 0 or any other value

```
         if($value!=0) 
         {             
           $jh ="update noti set noti='$value'";
           $res=$con->query($jh) or die($con->error);
          }
          else
          {
           $ab ="insert into noti(noti) values('$value')";
           $res1=$con->query($ab) or die($con->error);
          }
    }
```

Comment: the query which you posted above, it won't save the value into "noti" table

Answer (score 0):

not is reserved word. So you should use like this:

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO `not` VALUES((SELECT count(*) as count FROM register))";
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically i'm working on a project similar to Facebook Notification System

I've a Registration Form through which users are registered and all entries will be saved in a database named as "admin" with table name as "register"

Clear or not ?

Suppose I've 10 Users and I want to first show No. 10 as Notification Number at top bar as a popup tooltip

Just follow this example which i'm using 
[http://demos.9lessons.info/notifications_css/index.php][1]

After that I want to Perform this thing that when someone opens the notification bubble, that 10 Number Goes out and in backend, i'm thinking that to store that ROW COUNT into another table and after Jquery click function, that table value goes to ZERO and when any new user is registered, then it increments the counter with match the previous value..

Sounds or not ??